# Gitlab repositorie doesn't recognize my username information

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I already set my user.name and **email** as it is on my `Gitlab > Settings > Email` page with:

```
git config --global user.name "Joselito Doe"
git config --global user.email "my@email.com"
```

If I run `git config -l` I see the right information. But my commits still not linked to my gitlab user.
Also, If I run `git log` this is what I see:

```
commit 422986283ASDUHShu3hu3
Merge: XXXX
Author: Joselito Doe <--global>
```

`git remove -v` is right too. It should be my email there. Why the `--global` instead of my email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at some point, you type `git config user.email --global "your email"` and so `--global` was interpreted as your email for you local git config

Try this:

```
git config user.email
```

It will probably show you local config which is bad.

The easy way is to simply delete your local configuration (or overwrite it).

Use

```
git config --edit
```

to edit and fix your local git configuration.

Comment: Yeah. The entry `user.email` was duplicated. And the last one was `--global`. So I removed the entry from `~/.gitconfig/config` file and it's working. Thanks